# Images floated left and right with text between

Tags: columns

I need to recreate this in LaTeX:

[image: three-column section]

The rest of the page is "normal", i.e. no division into columns.
I have both images as separate files.
What would you suggest?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways of doing the above. The following in my opinion provides better control over layouts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.25\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \pgfimage[width=\textwidth]{fleft}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \LARGE {\itshape Accidental computational linguist}\\ 

    de facto web developer\\

    {\bfseries aspiring super user}
  \end{center}

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.25\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \pgfimage[width=\textwidth]{fright}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result.

[image]

Definitely you will want to tweak with the minipage widths and their placement options (`[c][b][t]`), font selections, text line gaps, and other similar issues, but I am sure you can figure that out.

Comment: Is there any benefits to using `\pgfimage` over `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. None that I am aware of. I have the personal habit of using `\pgfimage`, since I use Beamer a lot. But any user may want to use `\includegraphics` if one opts to.